# It is possible to know the Iphone's Contact DataBase struct? (iphone sdk)

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, contacts

I have to made an app, my app's users have a list of contacts, I would like to use the same DB struct of the iphone,also because I have to have the possibility to merge two or more contacts in my app's contactslist.
thank to all and
sorry for my bad English!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

You not acces to the data base structure but you can access to records and properties with interfaces.

Why you app contact list can't be in the iPhone address book ?

Comment: Thank you! I just found it now!